# How to validate picture captcha..?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

Here i have tried out giving user a picture captcha using google api..But the problem is even if user click on submit even without submitting captcha user is registered..!!
            here gose **.html** file

```
<form method = "POST" name = "register" id = "register" class="m-t" role="form" action="login.html">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name = "fname" id = "fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name = "lname" id = "lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name = "email" id = "email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name = "password" id = "password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="mobile" name = "mobile" id = "mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" required="">
  </div>
  <div  class="form-group" id="recaptcha_widget">
    <div class="required">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc4vP4SAAAAABjhRjyoMguw66mNSBgdpBF398AG"></div>
        <!-- End Thumbnail-->
      </div>
      <?php include("js/captcha.php");?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div cle the terms and policy </label></div>
    </div>ass="checkbox i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox"><i></i> Agre
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>

    <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.html">Login</a>
</form>
```

And here gose the **.php** file

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Send data and get response
    $cap = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Lc4vP4SAAAAAGOM8ERb1pYSBfHjiMGb9bnGVtog&response='.$cap);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    if($result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      print_r($result);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please check your result by use this code:  `print('<pre>');print_r($result);print('</pre>');exit();`. This will display result and stop execution so you can check the value of $result. Let me know what you see with this code.

Comment: There are some issues with the HTML here: `<div cle the terms and policy </label></div>
    </div>ass="checkbox i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox"><i></i> Agre` . Don't forget to finish the `div` tag and also `ass="checkbox i-checks">` looks like part of something that was started but perhaps not quite removed all the way.

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd  you mean->  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                               
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
                if($result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                print('<pre>');
                print_r($result);
                print('</pre>');
                exit();
              }
              ?>

Comment: @krishna: Please remove your secret keys. Do not spread it publicly.

Comment: sir.. sadly its not working..!!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: sir..!! the major problem is that when i click on submit specified in bootstrap file without even captcha check...user is saved

Comment: I'm confused, "here gose .html file" but it contain `<?php include("js/captcha.php");?>` php stuff.???

Comment: when user clicks on ** <button type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>** user is saved but their is no issue at all with it..but actual validation of captcha its done by api itself..!!problem is even with out captcha validation user is saved..!!:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97580/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-krishna).

Comment: i want if user dosent fulfills the captcha validating process he must get a error message or invalid nessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create demo with more clear and very sort line of code.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Addweb solution Pvt Ltd Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
    <form id="comment_form" action="verify.php" method="post">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="39"></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXX_SITE_KEY_XXXXXXXX"></div>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX_SECRET_KEY_XXXXXXXXXXXX';
        //get verify response data

        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            //contact form submission code goes here
            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
            //Your PHP stuff for use after captcha validate success.

        }else{
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
    }else{
        $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    }
}
?>
```

Please replace your site key with '*XXXXXXXXX_SITE_KEY_XXXXXXXX*' and secret key with '*XXXXXXXXXXXXX_SECRET_KEY_XXXXXXXXXXXX*'. Also use your mysql related logic into success validation block.

In future you need to check error message if any then you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#error-code-reference).

Let me know if there is any concern regarding this. Hope this help.!

Comment: Sir..can you plz guid me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236814/captcha-is-not-validating-in-jquery-side

Comment: its answered but the thing is even though the caotcha is valid...its throwing an alert "your missing captcha" please help me out of this..!!

Comment: Let me confirm that this alert display even you setup captcha correctly?

Comment: dint get you sir..!??

Answer (score 0):

Just do a JavaScript validation for empty captcha field in the client side and do allow them to submit the form at all if it is not filled! A very good example of this is available here: [ReCaptcha Validation](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-google-recaptcha/)

Comment: sir..can u plz instruct me how to do it..!!

Comment: What help you need? Client side validation or server side validation?  For server sided validation Google has already made its PHP code opensource. Have a look here: https://github.com/google/recaptcha