# Captcha is not validating in jquery side..!

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using php to validate the google REcaptcha..As far as the back-end validation gose is working out fine it giving error if captcha not submitted and if done user is stored in database but major problem arises when i connect it with jquery...thing is it is always giving out error "your missing captcha" every time even if captcha is validated in back-end, please help me out of this, pardon me if am wrong..!!

here gose **.php** file

```
                   <?php

        require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();

        // json response array
        $response = array("error" => false);
        if (!empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['mobile'])){
                /*
                if required include seperate validation
                */
                // receiving the post params
                $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
                $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
                $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']);

                /*
                validation process
                starts from here
                */
                // validate your email address
                if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        //validate your password
                        if(strlen($password) >= 6){
                                //validate your mobile
                                if(strlen($mobile) == 12){
                                        //validate captcha
                                        //your site secret key
                                        $secret = 'XXXX_secret-key_XXXX';

                                        if(isset($_POST['recaptchaResponse']) && !empty($_POST['recaptchaResponse'])){
                                                //get verified response data

                                                $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['recaptchaResponse'];
                                                $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
                                                $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

                                                if($responseData->success){
                                                        //Check for valid email address
                                                        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
                                                                // user already existed
                                                                $response["error"] = true;
                                                                $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
                                                                echo json_encode($response);
                                                        }elseif($db->isMobileNumberExisted($mobile)) {
                                                                        //user already existed
                                                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                                                        $response["error_msg"] = "user already existed with" . $mobile;
                                                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                                        }else{  
                                                                // create a new user
                                                                $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
                                                                if ($user) {
                                                                        // user stored successfully
                                                                        $response["error"] = false;
                                                                        $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
                                                                        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
                                                                        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
                                                                        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                                                                        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                                                                        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                                                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                                                } else {
                                                                        // user failed to store
                                                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                                                        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                                                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }else{
                                                        //failed to submit captcha
                                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                                        $response["error_msg"] = "Sorry this application is not for bots";
                                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                                }
                                        }else{
                                                //failed to submit captcha
                                                $response["error"] = true;
                                                $response["error_msg"] = "your missing captcha";
                                                echo json_encode($response);
                                        }
                                }else{
                                        //invalid mobile number
                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                        $response["error_msg"] = "Mobile number is invalid!";
                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                }
                        }else{
                                //min of 6-charecters
                                $response["error"] = true;
                                $response["error_msg"] = "password must be of atleast 6-characters!";
                                echo json_encode($response);
                        }
                }else{
                        // invalid email address
                        $response["error"] = true;
                        $response["error_msg"] = "invalid email address";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                }
        }else{
                //missing the required fields
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Please fill all the required parameters!";
                echo json_encode($response);
        }

?>
```

Here gose **.html** file in bootstrap

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>MiiSKy | Register</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "register.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>


</head>

<body class="gray-bg">

    <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen   animated fadeInDown">
        <div>
            <div>

                <!--<h3 class="logo-name">MiiSky</h3>-->
                <img src="img/landing/mii-logo.png">
            </div>
            <!--<h3>Register to MiiSky</h3>-->
            <p>Create account to see it in action.</p>
            <form method = "POST" name = "register" id = "register" class="m-t" role="form" action="login.html">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name = "fname" id = "fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name = "lname" id = "lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name = "email" id = "email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name = "password" id = "password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="mobile" name = "mobile" id = "mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" required="">
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group" id="recaptcha_widget">
                                                    <div class="required">
                                                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX_site-key_XXXXXX"></div>
                                                   <!-- End Thumbnail-->
                                                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>

                <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.html">Login</a>
            </form>
```

here gose the main **.js** file

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
    //execute's the function on click
    $("#submit").click(function(e){

        var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            /*jquery to call the url requested 
            and parse the data in json*/
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    fname: $("#fname").val(),
                    lname: $("#lname").val(),
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val(),
                    mobile: $("#mobile").val(),
                    recaptchaResponse: recaptchaResponse
                },
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                /*Give out the alert box
                to display the results*/ 
                success: function (json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }else{
                        alert("Registeration successful!",json.user.email);
                        $('#register').submit();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that you've included the necessary JavaScript resource to render reCAPTCHA widget properly, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the reference:

- [Displaying the widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Now comes to your user's response. The response from the user's captcha challenge can be fetched in three ways. It can be as,

- **g-recaptcha-response** - a POST parameter in the submitted form
- **grecaptcha.getResponse(widget_id)** - will provide the response after the user completes the captcha.
- A string argument to the callback function specified in the config object passed to the render method.

Here's the reference:

- [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

For you purpose use **grecaptcha.getResponse()** to get the user's response.

And as a sidenote use **grecaptcha.reset()** to ask the end user to verify with reCAPTCHA again. From the manual:

> If your website performs server side validation using an AJAX request, you should only verify the user’s reCAPTCHA response token (**g-recaptcha-response**) once. If a verify attempt has been made with a particular token, it cannot be used again. You will need to call **grecaptcha.reset()** to ask the end user to verify with reCAPTCHA again.

Here's your **HTML** code:

```
<form method = "POST" name = "register" id = "register" class="m-t" role="form" action="login.html">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name = "fname" id = "fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name = "lname" id = "lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name = "email" id = "email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name = "password" id = "password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="mobile" name = "mobile" id = "mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" required="">
    </div>
    <div  class="form-group" id="recaptcha_widget">
        <div class="required">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXX_SITE-KEY_XXXXXXX"></div>
            <!-- End Thumbnail-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>

</form>
<p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.html">Login</a>
```

Your **jQuery** should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //execute's the function on click
    $("#submit").click(function(e){

        var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            /*jquery to call the url requested 
            and parse the data in json*/
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    fname: $("#fname").val(),
                    lname: $("#lname").val(),
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val(),
                    mobile: $("#mobile").val(),
                    recaptchaResponse: recaptchaResponse
                },
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                /*Give out the alert box
                to display the results*/ 
                success: function (json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }else{
                        alert("Registeration successful!",json.user.email);
                        $('#register').submit();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

And finally your **PHP** should be like this:

```
<?php

    // your code

    //your site secret key
    $secret = 'XXXXXXX_Secret-key_XXXXXXX';

    if(isset($_POST['recaptchaResponse']) && !empty($_POST['recaptchaResponse'])){
        //get verified response data
        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['recaptchaResponse'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            // success
        }else{
            // failure
        }

    }

    // your code

?>
```

Comment: sir..!! i have updated my code but sadly its not working wen i am missing captcha..:( is my code correct..??

Comment: @krishna You didn't even read my entire answer, instead you directly jump into the solution. Your javascript resource should be like this, `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`. And  your `if-else` statements in `register.php` file are wrong and all over the place. Please correct those.

Comment: @krishna Did you correct this tag, `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`?. It should be `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

Comment: @krishna Here's your PHP code, [http://pastebin.com/XqX7tKV4](http://pastebin.com/XqX7tKV4). Please know that Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. Read documentations, search solutions and if you still couldn't find any solution, then ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Extremely sorry sir...!!

Comment: My mistake sir..!! I'll sure make sure to do it before asking it here!! Thanks again sir!!

Comment: @ rajdeep paul sir..please help me out of this i have completely updated my code now  i followed the same coding style as said but is still showing same "alert" that "your missing captcha"...am really in need of this solution sir..!!

Comment: @krishna Remove this line, `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`, you have already included javascript tag at the beginning.

Comment: @krishna Are you able to see your reCaptcha widget? Are you using right public key-private key combination?

Comment: smoothly sir...!! how can i thank u sir you save my whole day..!!