# reCaptcha / Form Validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, recaptcha

**Hello**,
I want to import reCaptcha(2) to my Register form. I have already imported, but their don't validate it. On submit click, skip's empty reCaptcha and ignores it. Can someone post **full HTML** & **JAVA/SCRIPT** code's(**without** using php). I can't find the right code. I want to have a full html/script code. :x

I tried this, but I need a `<script>` code to validate it. I searched for a code, tried some scripts, but it can't validate the `<form>`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="register.html">
<input type="text" name="name" required>
<br>
<input type="email" name="email" required>
<br>
<input type="password" name="password" required>
<br>
 <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY"></div></center><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need help with server side validation?

Comment: Yes, i think so, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to do server-side captcha validation, hence your `action` part of the form should be `register.php`, not `register.html`. Your HTML code should be like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" required><br />
    <input type="email" name="email" required><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" required><br />
    <center>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
    </center><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And this is how you can validate the input captcha in **register.php** file,

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'XXXXXXX_Secret-key_XXXXXXX';

        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            //get verified response data
            $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

            if($responseData->success){
                // success
                echo "success";
            }else{
                // failure
            }

        }

    }

?>
```

Here are the references:

- [Displaying the widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)
- [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

**Edited:**

From your comment,

> 2x borders on side of  . for example then i get a error, it add's a style(border-left:1px solid red;border-right:1px solid red;) or it add's a class(recaptcha-error). When success shows only the reCaptcha green mark withuot a border.

Here's the solution,

Your stylesheet should be like this:

```
<style>
    .error {
        border:5px solid red;
    }
    .success{
        border:5px solid blue;
    }
</style>
```

Your HTML will be as it is, and your jQuery should be like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[name="submit"]').click(function(e){
            var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

            if(recaptchaResponse == ""){
                $(".g-recaptcha").addClass("error");
            }else{
                $(".g-recaptcha").addClass("success");
            }

        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can i do without php? I'm using a application, and can't add a code on register.php

Comment: @o'Bass That's not possible. Since you have to perform server-side validation, you have to use either explicit form submission or ajax to validate the captcha.

Comment: Ou, Thanks you!
One more thing :
i searched for a code and fuond one(http://stackoverflow.com/a/27480486/5696491), can you please tell me, how can i add a red border if it has a error, without showing the alert message? i'm new on javascript, and can't find right code. Thank you.

Comment: @o'Bass Red border around the recaptcha or red border around the form?

Comment: Ahm, 2x borders on side of <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="SITE_KEY"> . for example then i get a error, it add's a style(border-left:1px solid red;border-right:1px solid red;) or it add's a class(recaptcha-error). When success shows only the reCaptcha green mark withuot a border.

Comment: @o'Bass I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: @o'Bass In addition, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34237593/5517143). It will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, Finally works! I got some error's, but i changed $(document).ready(function(){ to jQuery(document).ready(function($){ and from if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") { added a return false; for error, after else return true; with the codes $(".g-recaptcha").addClass("error");

Thanks very much!

Comment: @o'Bass Happy to hear. Please show your gratitude by *accepting* the answer. :)